# Redux - How to access the props in next state and avoid previous values getting retained on the page

Tags: react-redux

Redux - I am building two links in react-redux. Clicking on link2, renders datetime picker and some data below. User is able to view data for any date he selects. On page load, datetime picker always shows current date and time.

However, if I go to link 1 and then come back to link 2, previous user selected values are retained, it doesn't show current date and time.

Need some help here as to how to access props from next state

[image]